# inet_ntoa for ipv6 in perl

Tags: perl, ipv6, inet-aton

I am new to perl and I am trying to convert an ipv6 address in network format to the ascii string format. I could do this for ipv4 address using the "inet_ntoa" function in the "Socket" module. How to do this for ipv6 address without installing any new modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inet_ntop` as recommended by [perldoc Socket](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html):

> $string = **inet_ntoa** $ip_address
>
> ```
>    Takes a packed binary address structure such as returned by
>    unpack_sockaddr_in() (or a v-string representing the four octets of the
>    IPv4 address in network order) and translates it into a string of the form
>    "d.d.d.d" where the "d"s are numbers less than 256 (the normal
>    human-readable four dotted number notation for Internet addresses).
>
>    This IPv4-only function is provided largely for legacy reasons.
>    Newly-written code should use getnameinfo() or inet_ntop() instead for
>    IPv6 support.
> ```
>
> $string = **inet_ntop** $family, $address
>
> ```
>    Takes an address family and a packed binary address structure and
>    translates it into a human-readable textual representation of the address;
>    typically in "d.d.d.d" form for "AF_INET" or "hhhh:hhhh::hhhh" form for
>    "AF_INET6".
>    See also getnameinfo() for a more powerful and flexible function to turn
>    socket addresses into human-readable textual representations.
> ```